# how do I fix AttributeError: 'Tk' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to make a button that opens another python file

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('juststop')
os.startfile(r'C:\Users\75259\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\main.py')
open_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
text='calculater',
)
open_button.pack(
    ipadx=5,
    ipady=5,
    expand=True
)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried a multitude of things but non seem to work

Comment: If you want your program to open some other file you could use the `os` module and use `os.startfile(path_to_your_file_goes_here)`.  I'm not sure what you expect to happen in your code snipet? You are trying to use pythons built in `open` method on your root window which isn't a separate file like you asked about but rather an instacne of `Tk` [look at this documentation](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter16_os.html)

Comment: Well the assumption is that you know the file path.  If the file you want to open is in the same directory as your python script, then you can pass the file name as a string to the `os.startfile` argument. So if you had an excel file named "myfile.xlsx" then it would look like this: `os.startfile("myfile.xlsx")` and if it was located somewhere else then you need to supply the argument with the full path. So maybe its in a directory called "myfolder" on your c drive, then it would be `os.startfile(r'C:\myfolder\myfile.xlsx')`.

Comment: also, @Rory when I run the code it starts the os.startfile('') before I press the button also when I press the button it does nothing how would I be able to fix that?

Comment: That has to be caused by the formatting of the code. I would need to see what the code looks like.  Either open a new question and add your code that causes this issue and tag me or update this question to include your code and I can help you fix the structure.

Comment: @Rory I changed the post

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your `os.startfile` implemented calls the function right away.  One way to solve this is to create a function to use it when called and link it to your button.  Below is a modification of your example that will only open the file when you press the `calculater` button.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# root window
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('juststop')


def open_file():
    os.startfile(r'C:\Users\75259\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\main.py')
    

open_button = ttk.Button(root, text='calculater', command=open_file)
open_button.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=5, expand=True)


root.mainloop()
```